# Generate list with one string followed by a number of None values

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I'm trying to generate this list:

```
["var",None,None,None,None,None]
```

What's the **short** way to do this? I thought

```
list_2=["var",None for cnt in range(5)]
```

would work but it just generates an error. My second attempt,

```
list_1=["var"].extend([None for cnt in range(5)])
```

wasn't exactly a success story either. Could anyone please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can simply be done as

```
mylist = ["var"] + [None] * 5
```

The Reason,

```
["var"].extend([None for cnt in range(5)])
```

will not work, because extends changes the list in-place, but does not return the original list. You could have done

```
mylist = ["var"]
mylist.extend([None for cnt in range(5)])
```

Your second attempt

```
list_2=["var",None for cnt in range(5)]
```

is also not correct

1. Because its a generator expression without parenthesis.
2. Even if it would have worked, it would add what ever you get as the second item in the list

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea the "+" operator could be used on list objects at all! This is great guys! You rule!

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer _and_ point out the possible problems

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> list_1 = ["var"] + [None]*5
>>> list_1
['var', None, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.2

```
a=["var"]
_=[a.append(None)for v in range(5)]
```

another way with extend:

```
a=["var"]
b=[None]*5
a.extend(b)
```